# MVC: How to encapsulate logic in MVC ascx partial view with the same efficiency of webforms ascx controls?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have to build a few ascx partial views in my MVC applications to encapsulate re-usable functionalities as well as archive SOR and SOC. However, I encountered challenge how to encapsulate the business logic that drives MVC ascx views.

In webforms, the code behind of an ASCX control can handle a button click event and browser still shows the same page with only one postback. How can I archive the same thing in MVC? When ~/Address/Edit/2 includes an ascx partial view with a button on it that calls another MVC action - let’s say ~/ShareController/CommonAction – what is the best way for the CommonAction to return to the very same view that includes the ascx file?

Perhaps I am missing a common pattern in MVC web development?

Thank you,

Max

Update: Here is more description about the pattern I am looking for:

The partial view supposed to be an address editor. It can validate the address, shows 
validation errors and save the information back to the database.

The address editor is going to sit on many pages with different controller/actions.

In classic webform, an ascx control can perfectly interact with the user on its own through many postbacks without changing the url dor disturbing the overal page process. What is the right pattern for the similar scenario in MVC?

Update 2:

Not sure this has anything to do with the statefullness of webform. Totally different feature. This is about a controller call another sub-controller (or child controller) to handle a partial view. See my example at the end of this comment.

I just want to achieve the same level of encapsulation and separation of concern. If MVC framework doesn’t have that, it is a serious weakness.

In MVC, how could we have a “thing” (or partial view for lack of better alternative) that is able to handles the presentation as well as the logic and reside within another parent page without any interfere?

To my understanding, Partial views in MVC are just presentation that cannot have a dedicated controller without interfere with the main controller.  I hope I have got it wrong

To give you another example, consider this page that you are reading “stackoverflow.com/questions/{id}” . It includes an “Add Comment” component. The add comment might do server side validation to prevent invalid comments. How could you create an end-to-end “Add Comment” component that can reside on any page and handles necessary controller logic? The only way I can think of is to modify the controller of host page to be able to give user validation messages and ask them to correct the errors through post back. That means you add the component to 10 different pages, you have to modify 10 different controllers. That kills “DRY”

I DO HOPE THAT I AM WRONG! because I love MVC sofar.

***Conclusion:***

I marked Kenny’s reply as the answer; however, I would consider this as a serious weakness of MVC framework from the encapsulation, re-usability and DRY principal perspective.

My opinion has nothing to do with statefullness of webforms.

Please allow me to explain:

In webforms, You can 100% encapsulate a complex functionality in an ascx control and of course related classlib DLLs. One (1) developer can spend weeks developing it. Once his work is done, no one needs to know anything about it and just use it. The user control can be reused in many pages without bothering other “developer user”s with the detail activities that takes place within the ascx component.

In contrast you never can achieve the same with ASP.NET MVC where the ascx partial needs to interact with the user. Once the ascx needs to interact, it needs it’s own controller and the controller needs to preserve the ModelState.

Jeremy Skinner introduced the [ModelStateToTempData] in MVCContrib:
http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2008/10/18/storing-modelstate-in-tempdata-with-aspnet-mvc/
However, this is just a patch.

A good framework should allow developer to 100% encapsulate their work – in a control, partial, ascx or whatever – and had it to the rest of the team so they can “just use it” without knowing any data. Winform perfectly delivers this in many complex scenarios.

Any though welcome.

Comment: What is the partial view being used for in your specific scenario?  What is the purpose of the button click?

Comment: Hi Jeff,

Just added more comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if I get your problem to 100% but cant you just provide the UserControl with the data you need?

Pass in a <%= Url.Action() %> that the submit goes to when clicked on. If you then want the page to redirect back to the same page you were on you canredirect and re-save your ModelState (http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx tip #13). The redirect can be done referrer or by sending in the action and controller name to your action-method.

If that doesn't work you can always use Ajax?

Comment: Hi Kenny, Thanks for help. The link that you refered me says: "The MVCContrib project also has this feature but they are doing it in a single class which I do not like" Do you know what exact feature of MVCContrib is it talking about? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, they use the ModelStateToTempData filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure this is not how it's "supposed" to be done, but I usually look at the referer URL and redirect there.

Comment: Redirect doesn't work when the partial view needs to show validation feedback through a few postbacks. When you redirect ModelState is gone.

Comment: It seems that you're stuck with WebForms' "stateful" paradigm. Being an attempt at making web application work "just like" Windows application from the developer's point of view, it relies heavily on remembering form state between requests. MVC, on the other hand, takes web application for what it is: a series of independent requests. You should design your application in such a way that you don't require statefullness.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to handle this type of functionality in MVC (and practically anything else that isn't webforms) is through an ajax call.

Creating a full-page postback would be awkward, as you have seen. You can, however, accomplish everything you want by incorporating your post operation and validation error display in an ajax operation that only updates the portion of the page that contains the control, and not the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for same thing and I came across Html.Action and .RenderAction which seem to execute controller on the server and return/inject output.

That could be used for encapsulations and reuseability in MVC, but I'm yet to try it.